# Sync ignored files between git worktrees

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-worktree

I'm trying to start working with git work trees instead of branches. But when I create new corktree I have to manually move some files from main branch to new created folder. For example, .vscode/settings.json. So is it possible to sync files between work trees that should be ignored in git?

Comment: Ignored files (provided they're untracked that is) aren't *in* Git so Git itself can't do anything with them for you. But such files are just ordinary files in your working tree, so all of your *normal* computer commands work fine on them. Use whatever non-Git software you would use to synchronize these.

Comment: also, worktrees do not replace branches. They're two very separate concepts.